# Moving average from first to final value in a column

Tags: r

The data set consists of sequence of number like shown below. I need a new column that tells the average movement between the first value and final value. For example, in first row, the numbers are ( 1, 3, 5, 2), so the average movement is average(abs(3-1), abs(5-1), abs(2-1)) that is 2.333

`Sl no      Column A               req`

`1      1 > 3 > 5 > 2              2.333`

`2      2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5         3.75`

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: are you able to post the output of str(your_data_set) please?

Answer (score 1):

**1) dplyr/tidyr** Assuming the input `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, separate `Column A` into separate rows, summarize it and join the new req column onto the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Req <- DF %>% 
  separate_rows(`Column A`, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(`Sl no`) %>% 
  summarize(req = mean(abs(`Column A`[-1] - `Column A`[1]))) %>%
  ungroup

DF %>% inner_join(Req)

## Joining, by = "Sl no"
##   Sl no           Column A      req
## 1     1      1 > 3 > 5 > 2 2.333333
## 2     2 2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5 3.750000
```

**2) Base R** A base R solution used `AvgAbsDiff` which takes a character string of the form in `Column A`, reads it in using `scan` and computes `req`.  It is then applied to each row.

```
AvgAbsDiff <- function(x) {
  z <- scan(text = x, sep = ">", quiet = TRUE)
  mean(abs(z[-1] - z[1]))
}  
transform(DF, req = sapply(as.character(`Column A`), AvgAbsDiff), 
  row.names = NULL, check.names = FALSE)

##   Sl no           Column A      req
## 1     1      1 > 3 > 5 > 2 2.333333
## 2     2 2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5 3.750000
```

**2a)** This base solution does not use any *apply functions. Read in `Column A` into a data frame using `read.table` and then compute `req` from that.

```
r <- read.table(text = as.character(DF$`Column A`), header = FALSE, 
  sep = ">", fill = NA)
transform(DF, req = rowMeans(abs(r[, -1] - r[, 1]), na.rm = TRUE),
  check.names = FALSE)

##   Sl no           Column A      req
## 1     1      1 > 3 > 5 > 2 2.333333
## 2     2 2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5 3.750000
```

### Note

```
DF <-
structure(list(`Sl no` = 1:2, `Column A` = structure(1:2, 
.Label = c("1 > 3 > 5 > 2", 
"2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5"), class = "factor")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
data$req <- sapply(data$columnA,
                   function(x) mean(abs(diff(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(x, ' > ')))))))
```

`sapply` will apply the function to each element of `columnA`.

Then, working from the inside outwards:
`strsplit` splits the element in columnA on " > " resulting in:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1" "3" "5" "2"
```

`unlist` will turn the result in a vector:

```
"1" "3" "5" "2"
```

`as.integer` to convert it to numbers:

```
1 3 5 2
```

`diff` to compute the differences between the numbers:

```
2  2 -3
```

`abs` to take the absolute values:

```
2 2 3
```

and finally `mean` to take the average:

```
2.333333
```

**Edit:** Misread the question slightly, this will calculate the result correctly:

```
my.df$req <- sapply(my.df$columnA,
                    function(x) {
                      tmp <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(x, ' > ')))
                      mean(abs(tmp[2:length(tmp)] - tmp[1]))
                    })
```

Comment: For the second row i am getting the average as 5.2.5 . It is suppose to be 3.75

Comment: Ah sorry, read too fast. Thought you were taking the differences between consecutive values.

Comment: For `abs(tmp[2:length(tmp)]` you can just use : `abs(tmp[-1)]`

Comment: @ANG I realized that later, but my default (pythonic) expectation of `tmp[-1]` is that it returns the last element in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, but it could be written in a nicer way. Anyhow ..

Let me first re-create your dataframe

```
q <- data.frame(Sl_no=1:2, Column_A=c(("1 > 3 > 5 > 2"), (" 2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5")))
q$req <- NA
```

Which gives us:

```
  Sl_no            Column_A   req
      1       1 > 3 > 5 > 2    NA
      2  2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5    NA
```

Next, let's split this sequence into a R list:

```
q$A <- strsplit(as.character(q$Column_A), " > ")
```

And also add the length of this list:

```
q$A_length <- lengths(q$A)
```

Then, let's create a loop that will go through element 2: the last element in the sequence, subtract the first number in the sequence from it and store in a list. At the end of the inner loop we store the mean of this values in the corresponding row in `req`column.

```
for (row in 1:nrow(q)) {
    sum = c()
    for (number in 2:q$A_length[row]) {
        sum <- c(sum, as.numeric(q$A[[row]][number]) - as.numeric(q$A[[row]][1]))
    }
    q$req[row] <- mean(sum)
 }
```

Finally, let's print the created dataframe:

```
  Sl_no             Column_A                 A   A_length        req
      1        1 > 3 > 5 > 2        1, 3, 5, 2          4   2.333333
      2   2 > 5 > 1 > 10 > 5    2, 5, 1, 10, 5          5   3.250000
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope :) Actually Abs is missing here. Let me try editing the code. For example, if my numbers are 6,5,1,10,5 the answer is 2.75. but as per your code it is -0.75

Comment: Yes, sorry - so it should be `sum <- c(sum, abs(as.numeric(q$A[[row]][number]) - as.numeric(q$A[[row]][1])))`. Hope you managed to correct this by yourself!